# How to check multiple chekbox from database value

Tags: php, html, database, web, checkbox

I have this code to showing value from database as well as checking the checkbox that have the value :

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($kon,"SELECT jenis FROM pasien WHERE nopemeriksaan = $nopemeriksaan"); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $jenis = explode(",", $row['jenis']);
        print_r($jenis);
?>    
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkup" name="jenis[]" value="checkup" <?php if(in_array("checkup",$jenis)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    <label> Check-Up</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vaksinasi" name="jenis[]" value="vaksinasi" <?php if(in_array("vaksinasi",$jenis)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    <label> Vaksinasi</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="usg" name="jenis[]" value="usg" <?php if(in_array("usg",$jenis)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    <label"> USG </label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="xray" name="jenis[]" value="xray" <?php if(in_array("xray",$jenis)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    <label> X-Ray </label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sterilisasi" name="jenis[]" value="sterilisasi" <?php if(in_array("sterilisasi",$jenis)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    <label> Sterilisasi</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="operasi" name="jenis[]" value="operasi" <?php if(in_array("operasi",$jenis)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    <label> Tindakan Operasi</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cekdarah" name="jenis[]" value="cekdarah" <?php if(in_array("cekdarah",$jenis)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    <label> Cek Darah</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="lainnya" name="jenis[]" value="lainnya" <?php if(in_array("lainnya",$jenis)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>
    <label> Lainnya</label><br>
    
<?php
    }
?>
```

But however, it always just checking one value even when the array itself has 2 value. Is there anything I write wrong or anything I miss? Thank You very much for your help.

Comment: What _exactly_ does the array contain? Show a `var_dump` of it please.

Comment: `<label">` is a typo.  What is the value of `$nopemeriksaan` - is that a string or an integer?

Comment: @CBroe array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "checkup" [1]=> string(10) " vaksinasi" }. It should be checking the two checkbox, but instead it just checking one of them (checkup).

Comment: `[1]=> string(10) " vaksinasi"` - `vaksinasi` is only 9 letters (all within ASCII range, so character = byte), but it says the length was 10 here ... You got a _space_ in front of it here, so of course any comparison with _just_ `vaksinasi` will of course fail. It looks like your values are not separated by just a comma, but a comma followed by a space character? Well then you should explode by the same separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'll check if the result returned from the DB is correct by executing the query into the DB (basically validating the SQL)
I have doubts that you may need to put $nopemeriksaan in quotes. If everything is looking fine you can check if this part of your code is returning what you expect

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $jenis = explode(",", $row['jenis']);
```

I used to write PHP and if I remember correctly mysqli_fetch_array is returning an array so in this case instead of using $row['jenis'] you have to use $row[0]
If you still want to use the response as a dictionary you can use [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem where you are using the mysqli_fetch_array() function.

The mysqli_fetch_array() function accepts a result object as a parameter, retrieves the contents of the current row in the given result object, and returns them as an associative or, numeric array.

Syntax:
**mysqli_fetch_array ("database_name", "mode")**

Parameters:

1. *database_name*: The database on which operations are performed. It is a mandatory parameter.
2. *mode*: This is an integer value specifying the type of the returned array. The value of this can be one of the following −

a. MYSQLI_ASSOC

b. MYSQLI_NUM

c. MYSQLI_BOTH

That'll be all.